# Sqlserver standard trigger order

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, crm

I have database partially created and edited by an external CRM where certain tables have multiple (at most 2) after triggers on them. This is due to 1 trigger being auto generated by the CRM (over which I have limited control) and the other containing my code.

The CRM trigger generates the primary key for the datarow inserted. My trigger needs to access that primary key  in order to write it to another table as foreign key. I use

```
Select @id=max(id) from mytable
```

since Scope_Identity did not produce the desired result somehow.

This worked until I let the CRM recreate the table and its own trigger. The maximum id of that table selected by my trigger seemed to always be **actual_id - 1**.

When I altered my trigger using the same code it has always had the procedure worked again.

My question is:
Does SQL server (I am using SQL Server 2008) set its trigger order by creation time?

And:
Is

```
sp_settriggerorder @triggername='mycustomtrigger', @order='Last', @stmttype='INSERT'
```

going to change this permanently or do I have to call that procedure again, every time the CRM recreates its trigger? (using DROP and CREATE, not ALTER)

Hope the answers to that will help someone looking at the same issue.

Regards

Comment: `Select @id=max(id) from mytable` is broken for any multi-row statement. Why not just use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables in the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *documented*, but I believe that the `LAST` setting will stay with a trigger, provided it is not modified. (Contrariwise, it *is* documented that a trigger will lose this setting if it is modified). However, it seems to work:

```
create table T (ID int not null)
go
create trigger T_T1 on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T1',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
create trigger T_T2 on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T2',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
create trigger T_T3 on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T3',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
insert into T(ID) values (1)
go
sp_settriggerorder 'T_T2','Last','INSERT'
go
insert into T(ID) values (2)
go
drop trigger T_T1
go
create trigger T_T1 on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T1',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
insert into T(ID) values (3)
```

Results:

```
T1
T2
T3

(1 row(s) affected)
T1
T3
T2

(1 row(s) affected)
T3
T1
T2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

As to your first question, however:

> Does SQL server (I am using SQL Server 2008) set its trigger order by creation time?

It also *appears* to, but I *would not* rely on that. [`sp_settriggerorder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx) is the only place where any ordering is documented.

Finally, as mentioned in my comment, I wouldn't rely on your current `Select @id=max(id) from mytable` method - it could be broken for a number of reasons, but the most important is that a trigger is fired once per method, and may fire in response to *multiple* rows, so you ought to write triggers to use the `inserted` pseudo-table instead (and expect it to contain 0, 1 or multiple rows).

Comment: Thank you. I cannot rely on the inserted table for the id, because the id is being updated by the first after trigger. `Scope_Identity()` obviously does not help me here either when dealing with bulk inserts (though they **should** not happen in our case)